# Why is the Ajax code not posting to pho file?

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, ajaxform

I have a form which I am using to AJAX to submit. I have several forms using the same script all with different names posting to response.php however this particular form will not send.

When I remove my form name it tries to post in the normal way but when it has the correct name as the AJAX file I receive no reponse whatsoever leading me to think it is an error within the AJAX file.

HTML

```
<tr><Td>
<div class="row box" id="login-box">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-login">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="msg"></div>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error" style="display: none;">...</div>
                <form id="editMarshalTitleDetails-form" name="editMarshalTitleDetails_form" role="form" style="display: block;" method="post">
                      <div class="form-group">
<br><Br>
    <input type="text" name="content" id="content" tabindex="2" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $content2 ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="marshalColumn" value="marshalPackFrontPageTitle">
<input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo "$userID"?>">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 form-group pull-right">  
<button type="submit" name="editMarshalTitleDetails-submit" id="editMarshalTitleDetails-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
<span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-refresh" id="spinner"></i></span> Edit Title
</button>
                      </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            </tr></td>
```

AJAX

```
$("#editMarshalTitleDetails-form").validate({
    submitHandler: submitForm6  
}); 

    function submitForm6() {        
    var data = $("#editMarshalTitleDetails-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({                
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'response.php?action=editMarshalTitleDetails',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function(){ 
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#editMarshalTitleDetails_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; updating ...');
        },          
        success : function(data){
            $("#editMarshalTitleDetails_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; Template Updated');
            var a   =   data.split('|***|');
            if(a[1]=="update"){
            $('#msg').html(a[0]);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;                               
}
```

Comment: You can inspect the network activity in your browser and see if a request is being made to `response.php`. I am assuming that you've already checked the console logs for JavaScript errors. If you are getting a `500 Internal Server Error` then you'll want to take a look at your PHP error_log. Keep in mind the  `jQuery.ajax()` method does have a function to be called if the request fails.

Comment: Thank you - very helpful I managed to fix it